# Browser Scrollbar shift

Tags: html, scrollbar, css

When you go to page on my website where there is extra content, the scrollbar appears on the right, but it has a notiable shift to the left for my content. You notice this by clicking home and then hosting and back again on my site (www.ipalaces.org)

How can I account for the browser scrollbar on my pages? 
Can I make it so the scrollbar is always visible atleast?

My website is [www.ipalaces.org](http://www.ipalaces.org), please let me know.

Comment: For those attempting to reproduce, you may need to make your window smaller in size.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8. What browser are we talking about here?

Comment: All browsers, I am using 1360 x 768 res, 720P on my HDTV, so perhaps your resolution is higher which allows you to see full content, if thats the case try going here http://www.ipalaces.org/hosting/domains.html  and then click home to notice the difference.

Comment: See my answer below, tested in IE6, 7, 8, FF and Chrome.

Comment: I found a similar issue with some hidden divs using jquery, the bounce back and forth is even that much more annoying with the animation.  I am working on a javascript method of setting the centered content using the window with with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your body 101% tall... this will force the scrollbar to always show up.

```
body {height:101%}
```

Comment: That works good, but then there is an annoying 1 pixel downward shift. Is there not a way to make all browsers show the scrollbar but have it disabled if not needed. Like -moz-scrollbars-vertical; but more universal

Comment: html, body { height: 100%; margin-bottom: 1px;}

Seems to have lessen the gap, but there is still an annoying gap.

Answer (score 11):

Well, it depends on the browser.

```
body {

overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;

}
```

Should force the horizontal (`overflow-x`) and vertical scrollbars (`overflow-y`) to be displayed. Though I recall that Opera sometimes fails to respect the declaration, unless it's on an element within the `<body>` (divs and the like).

---

**Edited** with regard to @wsanville's, and @BHare's, comment.

Comment: This leaves an ugly double scrollbar when it needs it.

Comment: Define 'double scrollbar.' Two scrollbars together on each axis?

Comment: You should not apply the overflow properties to both `html` and `body` otherwise you will have two scrollbars! Yuck!

Comment: @wsanville: ah, so that's what @BHare's comment meant. I agree, that's ugly.

Answer (score 8):

I've tested this on IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 3, and Chrome, and the simple way to have a vertical scroll bar always visible is simply:

```
html { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: This seems less hackish then the awarded answer. http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work great for me...

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try... I know its ugly but it may be the only way.

```
#force_scroll { 
    width: 1em; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    bottom: -0.1px; 
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

And then in your HTML somewhere (preferably right before your `</body>`):

```
<div id="force_scroll"></div>
```

Comment: -0.1px is not a valid measurment. Even so, using -1px or -0.1em still leaves the same effect as margin-bottom: 1px;

The page can still scroll down 1 pixel.

Comment: @Brian, see the edit. Originally the `</body>` wasn't escaped/marked as code. So it wasn't rendered on page. I realise it's probably too late to be useful though.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

I had the same problem with even the newest Firefox (3.5).
The overflow function saved my life!