# How do I remove horizontal scrollbar padding (Firefox)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

To make a table scroll with a static header I added the following:

```
tbody.scrollContent {   
    height: 300px;
    overflow:auto;

}
```

And the html tbody tag has the class:

```
<tbody class="scrollContent">
```

It works well, but it added a horizontal scroll to compensate for the width of the vertical scroll bar. I would like my regualr table back with only the addition of the vertical scroll.  I tried the links below and other things changing the padding and all different widths of the table (td, thead, th, tr, etc) . It wont go away! Any help is greatly apreciated.
Thanks.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250353/internet-explorer-creates-horizontal-scrollbar-for-vertical-scrollbars-width)
[and this answer seems like they avoided the question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400992/i-need-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-on-an-overflown-div)
[and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203503/browser-scrollbar-shift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow-x and overflow-y are supported by IE5+/Win, Firefox 1.5+ (Mozilla 1.8+), and Safari 3+.

```
tbody.scrollContent {width:300px;height:300px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;}
```

let me know how it goes

Comment: That removes the vertical bar and hides the rest of the data. I changed the overflow-x to hidden, which does remove the horizontal scroll bar but the last column is cut off the width of the vertical scroll bar?

Comment: set the widths of your columns to fit in the area avaliable.